# Django, python sorting nested dictionary by date key

Tags: django, python-2.7

Below is print result of dictionary i am creating with the data from the db.  I am trying to show it in html with the date order ascending. But when i loop in template the order is not correct?  I have searched and tried ordereddict, created a custom filter -->

```
@register.filter(name='sort')
def listsort(value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict = SortedDict()
            key_list = value.keys()
            key_list.sort()
            for key in key_list:
                new_dict[key] = value[key]
            return new_dict
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            new_list = list(value)
            new_list.sort()
            return new_list
        else:
            return value
        listsort.is_safe = True
```

No luck !  Below is the dictionary that i have:

```
{u'Berplatform': {'days': {datetime.date(2012, 10, 31): {'': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 9): {<Event: Opening Coctail>: <Event: Opening Coctail>,
                                                          '': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 10): {'': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 11): {'': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 13): {'': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 17): {'': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 18): {'': None},
                             datetime.date(2012, 11, 24): {<Event: Platform is in Art İstanbul>: <Event: amberPlatform is in Art İstanbul>,
                                                           '': None},
                             datetime.date(2013, 7, 2): {<Event: ber12 exhibition 2>: <Event: amber12 exhibition 2>,
                                                         '': None}}},
```

Comment: Why not just order it in the queryset?

Comment: I am ordering in queryset doing order_by('beginning_date')... As you can see there is no problem in printed dict, but in template loop the order is not correct.

Comment: So how does your template loop look like?

Answer (score 0):

Custom template tag was the solution but i was using it wrong in the template. The below usage is true.

Custom template tag:

```
@register.filter(name='sort')
def listsort(value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict = SortedDict()
            key_list = value.keys()
            key_list.sort()
            for key in key_list:
                new_dict[key] = value[key]
            return new_dict
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            new_list = list(value)
            new_list.sort()
            return new_list
        else:
            return value
        listsort.is_safe = True
```

The correct usage in the template :

```
{% for venue, days in program.items %}
<div style='float:left; clear:both;'>
    <div class='boxRedBottom' style='width:100px;'>
        {{ venue }}
    </div>
    {% for key, values in days.items %}
        {% for key, events in values.items|sort %}  # Do the sorting of nested dict
            {% for event in events %}
                <div style='float:left; width:100px;  border:1px solid gray;'>
                {{ event }} {{ event.beginning_date }} 
                </div>
            {% endfor %}    
        {% endfor %}    
     {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```